# How to show tortoise SVN revision on my oracle forms?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, oracle-sqldeveloper, subversive

My SVN is tortoise, and I keep my Oracle froms on it. I wonder to know is it possible to show the revision of my .fmb files, on my oracle forms?

I want to keep the `$Revision$` or `$Id$` in when-new-form-instance and show it on the layout when I run the form. But when I added `:global.x := '$Id$'` in when-new_form-instance, and close the form, I cannot open it again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from SVN command line, you can just do:

```
svn info path_to_your_file.fmb
```

This will give you all information about your file. To get revision only, if you're on a Unix-like environment, a little grep should do the trick:

```
svn info path_to_your_file.fmb | grep revision
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, cann't I add a piece of code to my when-new-form-instance (for example) to keep the revision as a constant? For instance:  :global.revision := $id:$   and then assign this global to a text item to show it on the forms? I hope you understand what I am meaining :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if forms have ability to show some text-strings and you have free space in order to add this text:

- Read about svn:keywords, add Revision keyword as property to all forms and have `$Revision$` placeholder in the form sources.

Subversion keywords work on per-file basis, i.e it will show "Last Changed" revision for every file (doesn't have much sense, because SVN-revisions are global per-repository and changed last time in revision N file will have the same content in revision N+M)

- If you want to know latest revision of **repository** and show it in every form, you have to use SubWCRev keywords in files and use not result of export|checkout, but results of pre-processed by `subwcrev` *templates from repository*